# Change which ssh path

Tags: path

Good day all,

My `#which ssh` returns /usr/local/bin/ssh however I would like to return /usr/bin/ssh. Both /usr/local/bin/ and /usr/bin/ are in the $PATH. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have both of these? One ssh executable should be enough for anybody. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange `$PATH`. The first executable in `$PATH` is used (and that's what `which` returns).